# How to interrupt kevent() with signal sent to thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, kqueue

I want to notify a working thread with a signal - that it should stop waiting events and check some global conditions. I use `epoll_pwait` on Linux, and I want to do the same on Mac OS.

But `kqueue(2)` manual says:

> EVFILT_SIGNAL ... Only signals sent to the process, not to a particular thread, will trigger the filter.

How to overcome this limitation? Or may be there is another good way to notify sole thread waiting on `kevent`?

Answer (score 1):

Universal method for any I/O multiplexing API is:

1. Open a pipe using pipe() function,
2. Add its read end to your kevent/epoll/whatever set,
3. Write something to another end of the pipe to wakeup your event poller.